# Unity3D UWP Hololens: web portal input using InputField without pop up TouchScreenKeyboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I need to send remote input from the web portal to the HL2 in Kiosk mode, to control execution of my app as test participants use it. To achieve this I need to add an InputField to the scene. This works fine in Kiosk mode, but it comes with a TouchScreenKeyboard which pops up in the user's filed of view. The user is not required to input anything, so the keyboard is not required for them and is actually unacceptable for my needs as it ruins their interaction with my app. I know I can set the TouchScreenKeyboard to .Active(false) to hide it, but then the HL2 doesn't receive the input in Kiosk Mode. Previously, I had been taking the input from TouchScreenKeyboard.text instead of InputField.text, which doesn't work in Kiosk mode. The TouchScreenKeyboard doesn't appear in the scene using remote holographics in Unity, so I can't tell how to position it or interact with it, because it is not a GameObject and has no Transform. It just tracks with the user's head movement.

How can I hide or move the TouchScreenKeyboard in such a way that it still works in Kiosk Mode?

I need Kiosk mode to prevent the user from inadvertently launching the home menu or any other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device Portal Virtual Input can't send keyboard input while disabling the Keyboard or Input Field, it doesn't match your need to be a global input handler for remote keystrokes.

To receive remote input without a virtual keyboard and input field, you should
build your own server-side app to synchronize the remote operation to HoloLens.

Comment: Thank you Hernando. The funny thing is, I can deactivate the keyboard and still receive remote input in normal mode (ie not in kiosk mode).